# Sprite doens't display in release mode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to find out why a classed derived from CCSprite won't display in an layer in Release Build Configuration mode;

it works fine in Debug...

any tips? thanks

here is the code I am using in the CCLayer to add the sprite, the class itself has just few properties and methods:

```
   self.energyM = [EnergyManagement node];
    self.energyM.position = ccp(42,275);
    self.energyM.scale = 1;

    [self addChild:self.energyM];
```

Comment: in the [EnergyManagement node] ctor, there must be a reference to an asset (texture, other). Chances are it is not part of the release target. Check spelling for file names (spelling matters in Release) ...

Comment: Impossible to tell from this code fragment. Try reducing compiler optimizations in Build Settings to see if it is somehow related to optimizations.

Comment: I had removed any reference to name and it doesn't work, other sprites use the same texture atlas and they are working fine, it is almost an empty class...I don't undertand...

Comment: you were right. I changed the optimization settings and it worked. I have no time to check why, I will realease it asap. I will check later though. Thanks